# How can I make the dereference of a pointer hold a reference to the object?

Tags: c++

When I dereference a pointer and assign to it, it changes what the pointer points to, it doesn't call `operator=` for what it points to. I made this program to prove it:

```
#include <iostream>

struct S
{
    void operator =(int)
    { x = 5; }

    operator int*()
    {
        return &x;
    }

    int x;
};

std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& out, S const& s)
{
    return out << s.x;
}

int main()
{
    S s;
    int *x = s;
    *x = 10;

    std::cout << *x;
}
```

This prints 10. Doing `*x = 10` doesn't modify the object `x` points to. How can I make it do so? (C++11 solutions are welcome)

Comment: Your initial sentence is incorrect.

Comment: How could you possibly know when the assignment operator for assignment to an `int` is or isn't called?

Comment: Even putting the undefined behavior aside, your conclusion makes no sense.  If you say `*x = 10;`.  Then print `*x` and see `10`. How do you come to the conclusion that the object `x` points to was not modified, since the results are exactly what you would expect if it *was* modified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `std::reference_wrapper`:

```
#include <memory>
#include <functional>

int main()
{
    S s;
    auto x = std::make_shared<S>(std::ref(s));
    *x = 10;

    std::cout << *x; // prints 5
}
```

[Here is a demo.](http://ideone.com/XEXSiH#view_edit_box)

Answer (score 2):

Your code is undefined behavior. `int *x = S();` initializes `x` to an address to a temporary, which gets destroyed at the end of the full expression, so `*x` is illegal.

Answer (score 1):

The local `x` variable in the main function is of type `pointer to int`.  The `int` it is pointing to is the `S::x` *subobject* of the `S` instance, as returned by `S::operator int*`.  When you dereference it you get an lvalue of type `int` which is still the `S::x` subobject.  So when you call `operator=` on this lvalue `int`, it dispatches to the builtin `int::operator=`, not your user-defined `S::operator=`.

The user-defined `S::operator=` function is not "inherited" by member subobjects of a class.  I think this is what is confusing you.

If you want to use the `S::operator=` then you need to call it with an lvalue of type `S`:

```
int main()
{
    S s;
    S *x = &s;
    *x = 10;

    std::cout << x->x;
}
```

will do what you want and call `S::operator=`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you meant to define x of type S? There is no reason for it to call an overloaded operator when it is of type int.